# Google Maps API - get bound extent of Polygon onclick (Fusion table)

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with geometries. I am using Google Maps API to use fusion table in a website. I am able to select a polygon onclick. Is it possible to get bound of selected polygon using API?

```
layerb = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query : {
        select : "geometry", from : 'fusion_table_id'
    },
            styleId: 2,
            templateId: 2,

});

google.maps.event.addListener(layerb, "click", function (e) {

   var t = new google.maps.LatLng(e.row["lat"].value, e.row["lon"].value);
    map.setZoom(17);

});
```

Code is very basic, onclick will take stored lat/long (centroid of polygon) and will zoom.

Table contains 3 columns only : id, geometry and name.

Comment: What does your table look like?  You can query it for the coordinates of the polygon and then zoom the map to fit those bounds, I don't know that the geometry is available in the click event.  [Example of zooming to fit polygons from a FusionTable](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/www_advocacy_ucla_edu_Assembly_MapC.html)

Comment: @geocodezip: It is good example, I surely will try to use that code..